# Script Powershell delete keys Windows registry, vault and add network printer

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I want a Powershell script that will allow:

1. Deletion of keys in the Windows registry corresponding to 10.x.x.x (if not present proceed to step 2)
2. Delete an entry in the Windows Vault : 10.x.x.x (if not present proceed to step 3)
3. Add a printer by name \ 10.x.x.x \ Printer + Authentication on print server (Domain \ User with password by memorizing the information in the Windows Vault)

For my part I tried this :

```
Write-Output "===========Deleting entry Windows Vault==========="

cmdkey /delete:10.x.x.x

Start-Sleep -s 5

Write-Output "===========Deleting printer==========="

Remove-Printer -Name "\10.x.x.x\PrinterName"

Start-Sleep -s 5

Write-Output "===========Deleting old entries Windows registry==========="

Get-Childitem -path hkcu:\ -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object {$.Name -like "*10.x.x.x*"} |
        ForEach-Object {Remove-Item $.FullName}

Start-Sleep -s 5

Write-Verbose "===========Configuration printer==========="

$cred = get-credential "DomainName\" $domain = "."
$user = $cred.UserName
$PrinterPath = "\10.x.x.x\PrinterName" 
$net = new-Object -com WScript.Network
$pwd = $cred.Password 
$net.AddWindowsPrinterConnection($PrinterPath)

Start-Sleep -s 5
```

It is not very conclusive...
In the example above, is it possible to adapt the script ? 
For example, if you want to delete the registry keys and the Windows Vault entry, if the executed command does not find the requested information, make sure you do nothing and proceed to the next step.

Would it be possible to have help please ?

Thank you !

Have a good day.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your question. Are you getting errors when you run the script, or is it just not having the desired effect?

Comment: @Dicky Moore : I do not having the desired effect. Step 3, I wish to launch Wizard printer (by example with command : RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /il) and use the option "The printer that I want is not listed" and fill in the third field "\\10.x.x.x\PrinterName" with the authentification (DOMAIN\USER associated with the password). Because, I do not understand, in the step 3, credentials are not visible in the Windows Vault after the printer configuration by this. Once the computer has restarted the printer is no longer available. Need to enrich the script at all stages. Thank you !